# How can I remove a character from a match object?

Tags: python

A bit of data contains an an extra whitespace that I would like to get rid of, but unfortunately at that point it is a match object and so how can I delete it?

```
for string in sl:
    for keyword in keywordList: #looping through each string in syslog.txt against each keyword in keyword.txt
        if keyword in string:

        hostnameResult = re.search(r"\s[A-z]+\s", string)

        dateResult = re.search(r"^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}", string)

        del(dateResult[3]) <- the part I'm trying to actually do.

        print "**"+keyword+"**"+hostnameResult.group(0)+dateResult.group(0)
```

Comment: what is   `del(dateResult[3])` doing exactly? Also what are you parsing?

Comment: well im trying to delete the whitespace at pos 3 of the string which would be Apr  6 08:06:38

Comment: Using del(dateResult[3]) spits back an error however

Comment: so `dateResult[3]` is what exactly? can you add an example of the input and what output you expect?

Comment: dateResult[3] would be my attempt at accessing pos 3 of dateResult in order to delete the whitespace. But dateResult contains the regex match of the date, I can't delete it because it's a match object

Comment: why not just remove it when you get the string from the object?

Comment: How can I do that, the string comes from the object in the actual print satement where i do dateResult.group(0).

Comment: add some input that is causing the problem and the output you want